# How to extract a tgz which consists of many files present in multiple subfolders to another directory (ubuntu linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, tar

```
current directory
            ├──Folder1
                ├── sub_folder1
            ├──Folder2
                ├── sub_folder21
                ├── sub_folder22
                      ├── sub_folder221
            ├──Folder3
                ├── sub_folder31
            ├──Folder4
                ├── sub_folder41
            ├──Folder5
                ├── sub_folder51
```

Given the above folder subfolder hierarchy, which was compressed into one tgz file, I need to extract all files present in any folders subfolders, into one and only output directory.
Actually all files exist in the deepest path of each folder subfolder combination. for example in sub_folder1,sub_folder2, sub_folder221, etc. 
I have tried with the following:

```
find . -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar -xzvf '{}' \;
```

...but that outputs the exact hierarchy of files and subfolders, when I need all files in all subfolders, to be extracted to just one output folder `/path/to/one/folder`

Comment: Unclear: do you have one tar file or many?  (You indicate both.)  Also, show all the commands you have tried and their results.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

The `execdir` is exactly the wrong command for your task, it will change to the directory of the file.

If you use `-exec`, the working directory will stay the same and all tar files will be extracted from that directory.

There is also the option `-C` to make `tar` change to that directory.

```
find . -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar xzvfC '{}' /path/to/one/folder \;
```

or

```
find . -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar -xzvf '{}' -C /path/to/one/folder \;
```

Comment: Try the command I added.

Comment: i get following error:tar (child): C: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2. i also edited my question, perhaps it was missleading
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Try the changed commands.